# how to remove line breaks for a block element

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the line-breaks before and after the `<p>` element? I tried to use span instead of `<p>`. But what I wanted was a box with a height larger than the text I supply inside it with a particular background color. With span, I think this is not possible. If it is possible, or if there are any other suggestions, please help me.

Comment: You can use padding for span

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

this should help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
p {
margin: 0;
}
```

It removes both space above and under element.